# Close PopupJqueryDialogue with Iframe

Tags: c#, javascript, jquery, asp.net

I am Popup External url Page inside my current page using jQueryDialogue and Iframe

```
var iframe = $('<iframe frameborder="0" id="FrameCust" marginwidth="0" marginheight="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>');
            var dialog = $("<div id='tempstep'></div>").append(iframe).appendTo("body").dialog({
                autoOpen: false,
                modal: true,
                resizable: false,
                width: "auto",
                height: "auto",
                close: function () {
                    iframe.attr("src", "");
                }
            });
            $("input[id$='btnAddCust']").on("click", function AddCust(e) {
                e.preventDefault();
                var src = "../MasterPages/CustomerMaster.aspx?lpopup=True";
                var title = "Customer Master";
                var width = "980";
                var height = "530";
                iframe.attr({
                    width: +width,
                    height: +height,
                    src: src
                });                    
                dialog.dialog("option", "title", title).dialog("open");
            });
```

In my customer master Codebehind File Checking Query string to Identifiey the page from Popup or Itself (lpopup='True') 
I want to Close the PopupDialogue after click Save button inside the PopupDialogue (In the External Url)
how can i do that ?

Comment: can you provide jsfiddle for this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can pass query string in parent page from code behind of popup page using code below. This will also close the popup.

```
 Page.ClientScript.RegisterClientScriptBlock(this.GetType(), "jain", "<script type='text/javascript' language='javascript'>parent.location.replace('../test.aspx?Q=123456');</script>");
```

Comment: Yes its Working but its Initalizing My Page again Actually these popup is for adding Customer at the billing Time After add the customer Popup Close automatically and set focus to the next TextBox But if I do These  all Details entered by the user is lost how can i prevent Postback

Comment: if u just want to close popup then create a javascript function in parent page to hide the div named tempstep which contain the iframe. Then call that from popup code behind. Like this Page.ClientScript.RegisterClientScriptBlock(this.GetType(), "test", "<script type='text/javascript' language='javascript'>parent.somefunction();</script>");

Comment: Exactly am looking for these parent.somefunction(); Thank you